# ScrollView inside Fragment Relative layout is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using fragment to display registration page
I want "OTP" button stick to the bottom, so I used relative layout for that. I am using **linear layout** for edittext. When i click on edittext, keyboard appeared but when I am trying to scroll the page when keyboard is opened, its not scrolling at all
Someone please Help

Here is my fragment code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#F4F4F4"
tools:context="values.Registration">

<ScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F4F4F4"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:text="Mobile No. /\nमो. नंबर "
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="Mobile NO."
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:phoneNumber="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"
                android:textSize="17dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:text="Mail Id. /\nइ-मेल "
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="Mobile NO."
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"
                android:textSize="17dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:text="Name /\nनाव"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="Mobile NO."
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"
                android:textSize="17dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_send_otp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:drawablePadding="-40dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:text="SEND OTP / वो. टि. पी. पाठवा"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

in Manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```